# Inverse of =~ operator

Tags: bash

I want to check if a string does not contain any letters, I figured out how to check whether a string does contain any letters but I don't know how to inverse it so I don't have to go to the `else` block.

```
if [[ $var =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
        echo ""
    else
        echo -e "$ERROR, no description"
    fi
```

Comment: Did you try `if ! [[ $var =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]; then...`? Or just change the regex to `^[^a-zA-Z]+$` (all characters from beginning to end don't match a letter).

Comment: Yeah `!` did solve my problem